How to understand formulas with both bound and free occurrences of the same variable?
I'll begin with my (mis)understanding of what it means for a variable to be free or bound (within formal logic).
A variable is bound if it is within the scope of a quantifier, and free otherwise (authors disagree on whether a variable-symbol directly next to the quantifier is bound or neither, but this is an arbitrary choice of taste as far as I understand).
So, in $\forall xP(x)$, $x$ is bound. In the formula $P(x)$ however, it is not bound, and $x$ is merely a placeholder. Syntactically, this is quite clear, except for my question (feautured in the title). But semantically, I am still wondering a little what significance this distinction has. My question is also one of semantics, but I have a preliminary semantic question (I might be a bit off with my use of semantic versus syntatic here by the way).
My preliminary question is this: am I correct in thinking of bound variables as serving as tools to talk about sets? Because if I say for all or exists, then I am talking about a fact about a set; that all the elements of a set, or at least one element of a set, has some predicate. If this is true, then there isn't really any fundamental difference between free and bound variables, because using a free variable $x$ is basically just saying $\exists x$, where the set it belongs to is not specified further than the domain of discourse. Though this is kind of the case with bound variables in most of the formulas I have seen in texts about formal logic, because they don't mention the sets these variables quantify over (though I assume this is just an abbreviation in order to focus on other aspects of the topic).
With that preface, any underlying misunderstandings or ignorance regarding the subject of mine should be illuminated.
So, here is my question:
If $x$ features in a formula as both bound and free, like $Q(x) \land \forall x P(x)$, how am I to understand the different occurrences of $x$. If I understand the first as free and the second as bound, then I would think of the two occurrences as occurrences of distinct variables merely sharing a name; they are homonyms. This would be confusing, and I don't understand why anyone would do it. Perhaps however, the first occurrences is merely free upon first glance, but after co-occuring with a bound occurrence, it becomes bound? If this is the case, then that would be simpler, but it would also mean that a lot of the definitions I have seen of free and bound variables are incomplete (or at least unclear), since they do not mention this (as far as I have seen). Here is a source that supports the latter understanding (see the third paragraph). Here is a source that supports the former understanding. I am probably misunderstanding these sources, but my confusion should at least by clear by now.

I would understand it as: the person who wrote it made a mistake.  For example $\int_0^x x^2;dx$ is a mistake.  (Even though it was common in the 19th century.)

I wouldn't rely too heavily on Wikipedia for subtleties like this. That third paragraph is unclear, but it is consistent with your other source.

You can always $\alpha$-rename formulas to use the Barendregt convention, so that no variable appears both free and bound.

You write: "but my confusion should at least by clear by now".
I must admit that it's not clear to me what's confusing you, but I'll try to make a guess and write an answer. Tell me if I got it wrong, and I'll try and refine.
Technically speaking, if $P,Q$ are unary predicates, then $x$ is an element of the set of bound variables of the formula $Q(x) \wedge \forall x. P(x)$
This will be apparent if you look at the usual, recursive definitions of the sets $FV(\varphi)$ and $BV(\varphi)$ (of free and bound variables of $\varphi$) that logic textbooks normally give (though most logic textbooks tend to define only one or the other directly, since that usually suffices for what they want to do).
So $x$ is bound in the formula $\varphi$ ($x\in BV(\varphi)$) if it has a bound occurrence, and free if it has a free occurrence.
Furthermore, the variable symbol $x$ has a free occurrence (in the left conjunct) and a bound occurrence (in the right conjunct under the quantifier) of $Q(x) \wedge \forall x. P(x)$.
There's no contradiction between these two observations -- and hence betweem your two sources. It does not cause much difficulty, since every particular occurrence is either free or bound, and it plays nicely with most syntactic operations (such as choosing fresh names). It also acknowledges the reality that people tend to reuse variable names, both formally (e.g. in proof assistant software) and informally.
Goranko's slides explain in detail when, why and how you have to care about these occurrences (e.g. variables that occur free cannot be renamed "naively").

From the wikipedia article: " Since the same variable symbol may appear in multiple places in an expression, some occurrences of the variable symbol may be free while others are bound,[1]p.78 hence "free" and "bound" are at first defined for occurrences and then generalized over all occurrences of said variable symbol in the expression." What do they mean by "generalized over all occurrences"?

I think I have identified a part of my misunderstanding. In my post, I say "If this is true, then there isn't really any fundamental difference between free and bound variables, because using a free variable $x$ is basically just saying $\exists x$, where the set it belongs to is not specified further than the domain of discourse. " This is simply false. $P(x)$ is not true merely if there is some $x$ that makes it true. $P(x)$ has no truth-value on its own, it requires a variable assignment. But $\exists x P(x)$ is either true or false, with no variable assignment needed nor possible. Correct?

@user110391 That's correct with the usual caveat that the truth value of a sentence is defined with respect to some model - (e.g. $\forall x. x\geq 0$ is true in $\mathbb{N}$ with its usual ordering but not in $\mathbb{Z}$), and similarly the truth of a formula depends on both the model and a variable assignment which assigns elements of the model to the free variables.


A variable is bound if it is within the scope of a quantifier, and free otherwise.

Not exactly: observe that the variable $y$ is within the scope of the existential quantifier in the formula $$\exists x\, P(x, y),$$ yet $y$ is certainly free (more accurately: that sole occurrence of $y$ is certainly free).
Here's a better definition (hopefully it clears everything up for you):

An occurrence of a variable $x$ in a formula $\phi$ is bound/free in $\phi$ if the occurrence is/isn't in the scope of any $x$-binding quantifier in $\phi.$


If $x$ features in a formula as both bound and free, like $Q(x) \land \forall x P(x),$ how am I to understand the different occurrences of $x?$ If I understand the first as free and the second as bound, then I would think of the two occurrences as occurrences of distinct variables merely sharing a name.

No. In the formula $$Q(x) \land \forall x P(x),$$ there are two distinct occurrences of exactly one variable. (This is the conventional description anyway.) On the other hand, in the logically equivalent formula $$Q(x) \land \forall z P(z),$$ each of the two variables has exactly one occurrence.

Thank you for adding that note on the convention of calling it the same variable even though they essentially just share a name and nothing else, this will help me avoid confusion in the future.

@user110391 "...even though they..." Yes, (conventionally,) the word 'variable' does refer to the object's name, rather than its occurrence!
